# Python - Async vs Thread-based Producer/Consumer Pipeline

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I want to create a pipeline similar to this:

```
HttpGetHtmlFromA --|                                         
                   |--> ExtractComments --> ExtractKeywords --> NotifyOverHttp
HttpGetJsonFromB --|
```

I've two different approaches in mind for this, and I'm curious to get some secondary opinions on which would be best suited for the task.

The first approach would utilize threads, with each of the above operations (i.e. GetHtmlFromA, GetJsonFromB, ExtractComments, etc) running on their own, individual thread. There would be three different queues sitting between each of the integration points of the pipeline in order to pass the data down.

The latter approach I have in mind would do everything asynchronously. The above operations would be represented as individual tasks, with each running indefinitely within an asyncio event loop. Data would still be passed around via queues.

While I'm partial towards designing things asynchronously, I'm not sure what would be most efficient. Note that the HttpGetHtmlFromA and HttpGetJsonFromB are producers that poll urls. After performing their respective http requests, they'll delay for ~10 seconds before making a follow-up http request. This seems like a good fit for the asynchronous model as it allows for some work to happen between polls. That said, ExtractComments and ExtractKeywords have the potential to be longish running (mostly) CPU-bound tasks that parse the incoming content.

Anyhow, I'd love to hear your thoughts on the matter: threads vs coroutines. Is there an all together different approach that I haven't considered?

Comment: Are those long-running `ExtractComments` and `ExtractKeywords` tasks CPU-bound (and Python code, as opposed to GIL-releasing C extension code)? If so, doing them as coroutines will block your whole pipeline; doing them as threads will not, but it will still mean they can't run in parallel; doing them as child processes may be a better solution. However, you can still integrate them pretty easily with either asyncio or threads (e.g., via run_on_executor type methods).

Comment: At any rate, if you've only got ~5 tasks running, threads vs. coroutines isn't going to matter as far as efficiency goes; it's just a matter of which mental model fits the problem better in your head. And which libraries you can find to help—e.g., choosing between `aiohttp` and `requests` may depend more on one of them not having a feature you need, or just you liking one better than the other, and that will then determine everything else. Which means this is ultimately probably a subjective, opinion-based question which can't be answered on StackOverflow.

Comment: @abarnert Yeah, they are CPU bound. For the most part, I've found the operations to complete within a second per input. However, it really depends on the input they're parsing, which is being scraped from public sites.

Comment: If they almost never take 5 seconds, then there's probably no need to parallelize them. After all, if you're not going to be processing event N in `ExtractComments` while event N-1 is still going through `ExtractKeywords`, then either one can just use the whole core and it won't matter. Blocking your event loop is slightly more serious, but if you're careful, you can deal with that, because you're not running a responsive server. So, if that's not an issue, I don't think there's any objective problem with either design.

Comment: CPU-bound tasks are bound to the gil anyway so you can't paralelize them with threads. I would go for the async model and if performance becomes an issue for the processing part, maybe use a separate python process to leverage processing to another CPU core.